# How to search posts by multiple users?

Tags: support, search, users

I can search a particular user's posts by:

```
user:555
```

I tried to search multiple users' posts at the same time, like:

```
user:555 or user:666
```

But only user 666's posts come back.

Is there any work around?

Comment: Use SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1382435?userids=555%3B666

Comment: As far as I know the `or` only works with tags - so you can do `[tag-a] or [tag-b]` but not anything else. Not even `"word a" or "word b"`

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Search posts of multiple users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191532/search-posts-of-multiple-users)

Comment: @VLAZ The "Posts" table is too big for a LIKE-based pattern search, but it might work if it is pre-filtered by a tag or user id, and t-sql is enough smart today, to this filter first. For such things I would use google (the whole SO/SE is very well cached by google). Google is very weak in or/and expressions, more weak than the top search bar, but anyways it tends to give good results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work with the top search bar. The top search bar can only handle only AND relations.

But [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) does what you want. The query

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Score, OwnerUserId AS [User Link], CreationDate 
FROM Posts 
WHERE OwnerUserId IN (555, 666) 
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

is roughly what you want to have.

Comment: @Tomerikoo It supports, [your dictionary-tagged posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:6045800+[dictionary]) and [your upvoted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6045800+score%3A1..).

Comment: @Tomerikoo As the answer states, there is no way to search for 2 users, because it would be an OR relation. Only SEDE can do that.

Comment: @rene English is tricky, "only" belongs semantically to the "AND relations" and not to the verb. I always screw it up :-) Thanks the fix.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Filtering also for tags requires more complex query. PostTags is a bridge table between the Tags table and the questions in the Posts table. In the Posts table, answers have their question id in the ParentId column. So you need to left join posts with itself, and inner join it with PostTags and then with Tags.